# The meaning of the word nonce in a specific context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across this word in a biography of the Beatles and I can't grasp its meaning, so I would be grateful to anybody who could try to explain it to me. I looked up various definitions in a dictionary, but none seem to fit this. The following is an extract from the book:

> She said Michael was going to be a leader of men. I think this was because he was always arguing. Paul did things much quieter. He had much more **nonce**. Mike stuck his neck out. Paul always avoided trouble.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a misspelling, or mistranscription, or mishearing of **[nuance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuance)**?

Comment: I think it's a typo for nous : "common sense; practical intelligence" https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nous&oq=nous&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.861j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Well I myself thought it meant something like common sense and wasn't sure if I had read it correctly but it says nonce for sure. You may be right and it is probably a typo. Thank you.

Comment: That looks like a mispelling of "nous", meaning common sense. What did your dictionaries and search engines leave unclear, please?

Comment: I seem to have reached the same conclusion, it is definitely a typo for nous. Thank you :)